# JQuery getting data from XML URL and displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Im trying to get some data from a XML URL using jquery but I cant seem to get it to work. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I want to get the display-name data from each channel of the XML URL.

```
<div id="text"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.xmltv.co.uk/feed/6145",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
   });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {

$(xml).find("channel").each(function () {

$("#text").append($(this).find("display-name").text());

 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once one gets round [the CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), your code works for me. The jQuery you have is fine. I downloaded the XML file in question to my local machine, and changed the URL line in your ajax GET request to:

```
url: "6145.xml",
```

Comment: So I have to locally download it then get the data? Can I not just get the data without downloading locally?

Comment: Do you have access to the back end code? Browsers are blocked but you could GET the XML from your server (PHP, Ruby, ASP.Net, etc.) and make it available to your jQuery that way. If that's not an option, I suggest you reach out to the XMLTV folk and ask whether they can enable CORS. Based on my reading of their business model, it would seem to be a sensible request for them to entertain.

Comment: is there a way i can download the xml in jquery? i know i can right click 'save page as' file.xml, but is there a way to do in automatically via jquery?

Comment: No there isn't. I know the feeling! If your skills are purely front-end, then you'll need to either ask for them to add CORS or put up with manually downloading the XML yourself. I expect the latter is not viable for you.